# Liouville theorem and the ergodic assumption

Tags: statistical-mechanics, mathematical-physics, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space, complex-systems

I am following a course on statistical mechanics. My instructor presented us the following **Liouville theorem** in two (claimed) equivalent ways:

1. **Differential statement**: The probability distribution $\rho(p,q)$ characterizing a statistical ensemble over the microstates of a system described by a Hamiltonian $H(p,q)$ is such that $\frac{d}{dt}\rho(p,q)=0$
2. **Integral statement**: the Hamiltonian flow $g^t$ preserves phase space volume, hence for any t $|g^t(V)|=|V|$. (A consequence of this is the Poincaré recurrence theorem).

On the other hand we assumed the following **Ergodic assumption**, fundamental to all the discussion:

3. Time averages $\langle O\rangle_t$ equal ensemble averages $\langle O\rangle_E$, where for time averages one intends $\frac{1}{\tau}\int_{0}^{\tau} O(p(t),q(t))d\tau$ with $p(t),q(t)$ being the solution of Hamilton Equations.

Moreover we assumed the **Equal Apriori Probability Postulate**, stating that any microstate leading to the same macrostate should be equally probable, for an isolated system.

Now my questions are:

- Why it holds 1 iff 2?
- In the proof of 1, we showed that the Hamiltonian velocities vector $v=(p',q')$ has zero divergence and then resorted to a continuity equation $\partial_t\rho+div(\rho)=0$ for $\rho$: what assures that this continuity equation should hold?
- Moreover we wrote $\rho=Jv$ linking hence the density $\rho$ and the
  Hamiltonian velocities $v$: what assures we can do this? I understand
  that the ergodic assumption must involve some kind of compatibility
  between the Hamiltonian flow and $\rho$ but why *this* kind of
  compatibility? How can this idea of compatibility be rigorously
  formalized?
- Are the Ergodic assumption and the Equal Apriori Postulate linked or independent?

Comment: You could read Chapter 2 in Khinchin's classical book "Mathematical Foundations of Statistical Mechanics". There is also a deep discussion (both at the physical and mathematical levels) of the bases of statistical mechanics in Gallavotti's "Statistical Mechanics: a Short Treatise". (It is not very difficult to find copies of both books on the internet.)

Comment: I agree, Gallavotti's works on the foundations of stat. mech. are great. More links in this answer (useful for the part "Are the Ergodic assumption and the Equal Apriori Postulate linked or independent?"): https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/731693/226902